# How do I feed data into this model?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

Currently, I am making a CNN that inputs an image file of an airfoil, and outputs its lift coefficient. The model itself is:

```
input_img = Input(shape(100,100,1), dtype='int32', name = 'img_input')

Layer = Conv2D(32,(3,3))(input_img)

Layer = MaxPooling2D((3,3))(Layer)

Layer = Conv2D(32,(3,3))(Layer)

Layer = MaxPooling2D((3,3))(Layer)

Layer = Flatten()(Layer)

Layer = Dense(32, activation = 'relu')(Layer)

end_out = Dense(1, kernel_initializer = 'normal')

model = Model(inputs=[img_input],outputs=[end_out])

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer='adam')
```

To me, it seems like I would have to pair image data up with the output data, then train the network on the paired datasets. However, I'm not sure if this is the correct method, and if it is, I don't know how to do it. How would I train this model on image data as the input, and numerical data (lift coefficients) as the output?
Thanks!

Comment: you need to make this example reproducible. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also is this a statistics question or a programming question? are you getting syntax or other errors that would fixed with programming knowledge?

Comment: I'll switch it over to statistics. I just figured that people with knowledge in ML would know how to do this.

Also, I suppose my question should be changed to "How do I label the data in this regression problem?"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Keras Documentation you must fit the data and learn weights from the data

```
# For a single-input model with 10 classes (categorical classification):

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', input_dim=100))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Generate dummy data
import numpy as np
data = np.random.random((1000, 100))
labels = np.random.randint(10, size=(1000, 1))

# Convert labels to categorical one-hot encoding
one_hot_labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(labels, num_classes=10)

# Train the model, iterating on the data in batches of 32 samples
model.fit(data, one_hot_labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

Comment: https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/

Comment: The only issue I have with this is that it is a regression problem. Thus, I need to label my data with the outputs, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Do you mean you have unlabeled data ?

Comment: For Supervised learning it is mandatory to have <input,Ouput> Pairs to learn from. If you have labelled data may be try checking this for Linear Regression http://briandolhansky.com/blog/artificial-neural-networks-linear-regression-part-1 . Your output value will one output that is an integer.

Comment: Just as in your question you have mentioned that you input is an image which is of size shape(100,100,1) and each of whose value is a dtype='int32' the output will be single value i.e. the output of the dense function of dtype='int32' or data type of greater size based on the range of values you are expecting as output

Comment: Thank you so much!